# Why does the QMainWindow not show?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

Apologies for the generic title, I couldn't synthetize the issue enough to fit in the title.

I'm using the Qt Creator "Qt for Python - Window (UI)" project template, selecting `QMainWindow` as the base class for the generated class (UI + python class). **I then make no modification to the actual code** and simply try to run the main file, but the window doesn't show:

[image: window output]

It just opens a very small empty window, but it misses the status bar, menu bar and any other content I add to the window's ui file (to double-check that this is indeed the case, I also tried adding a QLabel item in the ui file, but the result is the same).

The files produced by Qt Creator are these:

```py
# main.py
import sys
import os


from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = MyMainWindow()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MyMainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MyMainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MyMainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

From all sources I could find, this code seems correct: first the App instance is created, then the main window is created and shown, finally the event loop is started. If, instead of choosing `QMainWindow` as the base class in the project setup wizard, I choose `QWidget`, the content renders as expected (but then I can't define menus in the UI file).

Can anyone please explain me what I'm doing wrong? (Versions info: Qt 5.15.2, PySide2, python 3.8)

---

#### Edit

For those landing here with the same issue, though the linked "duplicate" is for an unrelated symptom, the solution to that problem and this is the same. Look at the "Why does that happen?" part, the automatically generated code from QtCreator is wrong for QMainWindow subclasses.

Comment: Could it be that `ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)` or `loader.load(ui_file, self)` failed? Btw did you verify that the bars are really not displayed by adding something to them?

Comment: @eyllanesc that works, though that's very confusing. In principle, the outer class could be anything and it doesn't have to be a QMainWindow subclass, as all the code does is create a (different) QMainWindow instance based on the ui file's content and show that one. Why, then, is the autogenerated code subclassing at all?

Comment: @GPhilo I don't understand you, but the cause of the error is that QUiLoader.load creates a new instance and that method does not work to create classes.  Finally, avoid asking about the reason for the DVs since in SO it has reached a consensus that there is no need to justify them

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes, my explanation was a bit too cryptic, but [looking at the PySide6 example](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html#option-b-loading-it-directly) I see that they use the returned object directly.

Comment: exact, and that object is different from the one you used, so you have 2 windows: the first is empty and visible, and the second is filled but hidden

Comment: About the request for explanations, I still believe giving a reason on why someone thinks a question is bad helps the asker improve the general quality of the questions. There may be no *need* to justify downvotes, but asking for a reason why a question is deemed low quality doesn't mean the downvoter is *required* to answer :) It'd just be good courtesy.

Comment: @GPhilo No, a consensus has also been reached that asking why the DV is noise, does not bring any advantage, and it is recommended to raise a flag indicating that it is "It's no longer needed" for it to be eliminated and that is what I have done .

Comment: The duplicate is the same: *Why an empty window is shown?*, in both cases the same is explained (not only read the title but the explanation that the OP does) and the answer is that you are creating 2 windows as I already explained in my old commentary

Comment: On that, I disagree. The underlying reason for the erroneous behaviour may be the same, but that's not obvious at all to a non-expert. The linked question talks about signals not being triggered, while the code I show is the auto-generated code from the IDE, which is supposed to work. I went over the linked question and its answer, but the answer contains a lot of noise towards answering *this*, simpler, question. I stand by my thought that that is not a duplicate, but that's irrelevant. The edit is meant towards others like me who just search for the reason why the IDE code doesn't work.